# Office custom toolbar location

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007

I have created a custom toolbar in my Office package (e.g. Word, Excel, Outlook). My profile got corrupted so I have to create a new profile. Does anyone know where the location of these toolbars is as I would like to copy them into my new profile.

I'm using Office 2007 on Windows XP SP3 and I still have my old profile backup.

Answer (score 0):

Custom toolbars are stored in your NORMAL.DOTm or NORMAL.DOT file.

These are usually stored in \docs and settings\username\Application Data\Microsoft\templates